# How to fix a corrupted (boilerplate) toplevel.cmake file?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I accidentally replaced my CMakeLists.txt file in my catkin_ws/src directory and then ran catkin_make. This replaced the `toplevel.cmake` located in this directory `/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake`. Resulting in the following error:

---

```
CMake Error: File /home/user/projects/catkin_ws/src/package.xml does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake:10 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:61 (stamp)  
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:39 (_catkin_package_xml)  
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:95 (catkin_package_xml)  
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (catkin_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:112 (message):
  catkin_package() 'catkin' must be listed as a buildtool dependency in the
  package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (catkin_package)
```

---

This is the same question asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/188096/failing-to-create-catkin-workspace/), however I'm not able to follow the answer given. I tried of replacing the `toplevel.cmake` located in the directory the `/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake`, however I couldn't find the original one (or how to generate it again).

To be more specific, I would like to know what the best way to proceed is (should I reinstall ROS or is there a better solution?).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227161/how-to-fix-a-corrupted-(boilerplate)-toplevel.cmake-file?/) by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-20**:
For future questions: please use the *Preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it) for console copy/pastes instead of *Block quote*. As the name suggests, it preserves the formatting better (Block quote rearranges things in sometimes unpredictable ways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First try to `unlink` / `rm` the `src/CMakeLists.txt` in your workspace.

Then try building your workspace again (just run `catkin_make` in `/home/user/projects/catkin_ws`). That should work, provided you did not actually edit the file in `/opt/ros/indigo/..` (that would have required `sudo`, so you should know / remember that).

If you did change `toplevel.cmake` *itself*, then you can just re-install the `ros-$DISTRO-catkin` package using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin
```

for Indigo.

That should replace the edited file with the original version. Building your workspace should now work again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-02-20**:
Thank you very much! That worked perfectly!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-20**:
Good to hear you got it fixed. Can you tell us which of the two possible fixes worked for you?

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-02-20**:
I had to do the re-install of catkin (i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin`), since the `toplevel.cmake` file in the `/opt` directory was indeed the wrong one.